# why linkbutton control ID changes on the server online?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

hi guys i'm using **javascript** to make **some events based on the clicked linkbutton** by using the **ID of the linkbuttons** here the code of my asp page

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Tlbr_Item_New" runat="server" CssClass="button_big">Tlbr_Item_New</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Tlbr_Item_Save" runat="server" CssClass="button_big" OnClientClick="return ToolBarClickItem(this);" >Tlbr_Item_Save</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Tlbr_Item_delete" runat="server" CssClass="button_big" OnClientClick="return ToolBarClickItem(this);" >Tlbr_Item_delete</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Tlbr_Item_Undo" runat="server" CssClass="button_big" OnClientClick="return ToolBarClickItem(this);" >Tlbr_Item_Undo</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Tlbr_Item_Clear" runat="server" CssClass="button_big" OnClientClick="return ToolBarClickItem(this);" >Tlbr_Item_Clear</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Tlbr_Item_Search" runat="server" CssClass="button_big" OnClientClick="return ToolBarClickItem(this);" >Tlbr_Item_Search</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Tlbr_Item_Print" runat="server" CssClass="button_big" OnClientClick="return ToolBarClickItem(this);" >Tlbr_Item_Print</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Tlbr_Item_Close" runat="server" CssClass="button_big" OnClientClick="return ToolBarClickItem(this);" >Tlbr_Item_Close</asp:LinkButton>
```

**and here is my javascript function**

```
function ToolBarClickItem(Item) {
window.style = "cursor:hand;";
var bRes = true;
var sMessage = "";
var ItemID = "";
if (typeof Item == 'object')
    ItemID = Item.id;
else
    ItemID = Item;
switch (ItemID) {
    case "Tlbr_Item_New":
        if (NewButtonURL != "")
            bRes = eval(NewButtonURL);
        break;
    case "Tlbr_Item_Save":
        if (SaveButtonURL != "")
            bRes = eval(SaveButtonURL);
        if (bRes == true) {
            if (IsAnyRequiredEmpty(document.forms[0])) {
                window.alert(ErrorEmptyNotAllowed);
                bRes = false;
            }
            else
                sMessage = WarnMessageArray[ItemID];
        }
        break;
    case "Tlbr_Item_delete":
        if (DeleteButtonURL != "")
            bRes = eval(DeleteButtonURL);
        sMessage = WarnMessageArray[ItemID];
        break;
    case "Tlbr_Item_Undo":
        if (UndoButtonURL != "")
            bRes = eval(UndoButtonURL);
        sMessage = WarnMessageArray[ItemID];
        break;
    case "Tlbr_Item_Clear":
        if (ClearButtonURL != "")
            bRes = eval(ClearButtonURL);
        break;
    case "Tlbr_Item_Search":
        if (SearchButtonURL != "")
            bRes = eval(SearchButtonURL);
        break;
    case "Tlbr_Item_Print":
        if (PrintButtonURL != "")
            bRes = eval(PrintButtonURL);
        if (bRes == true && bFreeSearch == false)
            if (IsAnyPrimaryEmpty(document.forms[0])) {
                window.alert('No Record To Print');
                bRes = false;
            }
            else
                CustomPrint(PrintURL);
        break;
    case "Tlbr_Item_Close":
        if (confirm('سيتم إغلاق الشاشة؟'))
            window.close();
        bRes = false;
        break;
}
if (sMessage != "" && bRes == true)
    bRes = ShowAskMessage(WarnMessageArray[ItemID]);
return bRes;
```

}

when i test it on local IIS it works good

but when i publeshed it on my server which is somee.com
the linkbuttons controls changes to ctloo_Tlbr_Item_Save and it dose not working
so i do not know the problem and what is the solution

Comment: You should probably also get rid of all the eval you are using with better / proper implementation. What can be the content of the string values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    switch (ItemID) {
        case '<%= Tlbr_Item_New.ClientID %>':
            //Your code
            break;
        case '<%= Tlbr_Item_Save.ClientID %>':
            //Your code
            break;
        case '<%= Tlbr_Item_delete.ClientID %>':
            //Your code
            break;
        case '<%= Tlbr_Item_Undo.ClientID %>':
            //Your code
            break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ClientIdMode=Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx).

You can set the `ClientIDMode` value for all pages in a Web site by setting the pages element in the site's `Web.config` file. You can set the ClientIDMode value for a page in the `@Page directive`. With .NET4 you can even set it for a control via [`Control.ClientIdMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx).

The default value of ClientIDMode for a page is `Predictable`. The default value of ClientIDMode for a control is `Inherit`.

[ClientIDMode in ASP.NET 4.0](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40)

However, you can also get the client ids via `ClientID`: `$("#<%= Tlbr_Item_Save.ClientID %>")`

[A generic way to find ASP.NET ClientIDs with jQuery](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Oct/15/A-generic-way-to-find-ASPNET-ClientIDs-with-jQuery)

Comment: i've tried your way but i got strange **The type or namespace name 'ClientIDMode' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)** and i,m using .net framwork 4.0

Comment: @AhmedKamal: Check the application pool in IIS which your application is assigned  to. It should use .NET 4.